# Voice recognition in Raspberry Pi in custom language

Tags: audio, speech-recognition, locale, text-to-speech

I want to build a voice controlled system for very simple tasks using the RPi. Like lighting an LED or running a motor. But I want to set up the voice system in my own language and define my own custom words and actions associated with them. I am not looking for creating complex commands such as searching online etc. Is this doable? Where do I even begin?

Comment: I would start with controlling a motor led etc. then add voice control (normal language) and only when I was sure the first two worked as expected go about inventing my own language. If not done this way you will have a nightmare trying to debug the system. Does it not work because of an electronics problem? Software? the voice recognition? the parser? pattern matcher? etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But again, how do you get started on the speech recognition part?

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange Network. I think Mr @SteveRobillard has not noticed that English may __not be your native language__ and that you want to know if there are any speech recognition systems/libraries/methods that work for _other, __real___ languages used in the world at the moment, not ones that are being constructed by the coder or a group of enthusiasts. (I guess Esperanto and Klingon are included in the former groups)...!

Answer (score 1):

According to this related question on our sister Stack Exchange "[Can I get Speech Recognition in language other than English on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227434/can-i-get-speech-recognition-in-language-other-than-english-on-android)" Pocket Sphinx might be a possible route to go down.  The answer there suggested that it only had Language Models and Dictionary Files for English languages - perhaps that has improved since the answer was given a couple of years ago.

For the record Pocket Sphinx is one of a group of Speech recognition engines collective called [CMU Sphinx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMU_Sphinx) from Carnegie Mellon University.

Answer (score -1):

you can refer this link : https://diyhacking.com/best-voice-recognition-software-for-raspberry-pi

and also this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827178/voice-to-text-translator-raspberry-pi

Comment: We're trying a new policy with regard to informationless link-only answers here. If this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.